# changing Font size in html style attribute

Tags: html, css

difference between both and why we use the % symbol and what does it means?

`<p style="font-size:160%;">This is a paragraph.</p>`

`<p>This is a paragraph.</p>`

Comment: Have you read any documentation about CSS? You are going to find an answer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one has the style attribute (CSS) of `font-size:160%` it sets the font-size property to 160%.
`%` is a relative [CSS unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp), it will set the font size to 160 percentage of the parent element.

```html
<div style="font-size:24px;">
  <p style="font-size:160%;">This is a paragraph with 160% of the font size of parent div</p>
  <p>This is a paragraph with the font size of the parent div</p>
</div>
```